# Top/Bottom Padding inside Nested Divs with Percentages

Tags: html, css, nested, padding

I'm having a trouble dealing with the padding inside a nested div.

The problem is that I have a banner on top (Small Bar) and another one below that with more content called the Banner. The banner's height is 150px, and I wish to make that entire space padded at the top and bottom for 10%. I also have a "center" div included in the "bannerspace" div which centers all of the content into a straight line down the middle for organization.

However, whenever I apply padding-top: 10%, the padding is applied to the entire body element, making the padding much larger than I expected.

I have spent a few hours looking for solutions and even asked my web-dev friend, and I could not get a working answer. I've found that this may be an expected behavior for vertical padding, but I'm not sure if any of you have solutions.

I have tried changing the positioning of most elements as well as the box-sizing method, neither of which have helped. I also tried using a margin, but the same problem still applies.

Here is my HTML for the body (Head is irrelevant):

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <!--Header Bar (Top) - "Stats" on PD-->
        <div class="center">
            <div class="stat1">
                Filler: <br>
                Test
            </div>
            <div class="stat2">
                Filler: <br>
                Test
            </div>
            <div class="stat3">
                Filler: <br>
                Test
            </div>
            <div class="stat4">
                Filler: <br>
                Test
            </div>
            <div class="stat5">
                Filler: <br>
                Test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
        <!--Banner Bar (Middle) - "Banner" on PD-->
        <div class="center">
            <div class="bannerlogo">
                Logo
            </div>
            <div class="bannerspace">
                <div class="loginarea">
                Filler
                </div>
                <div class="registerarea">
                Filler
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    This will be the homepage!
    <form name="input" action="LoginPage.html" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    <form name="input" action="AccountPage.html" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Account">
    </form>
    <form name="input" action="OtherPage1.html" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Other 1">
    </form>
    <form name="input" action="OtherPage2.html" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Other 2">
    </form>
    <form name="input" action="OtherPage3.html" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Other 3">
    </form>
</body>
```

And my CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: "Roboto Normal 400", "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;

}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #DAFFDA;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}


.center {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    position: absolute;
}

.header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px solid black;
    background-color: #7C7C7C;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-color: #3D3D3D;
    position: relative;
}

.banner {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px solid black;
    background-color: #6EFF81;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-color: #3D3D3D;
    position: relative;
}

.bannerlogo {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    height: 80%;
    width: 36%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
    line-height: 120px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
}

.bannerspace {
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-top: 10%;
}

.loginarea{
    height: 80%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.registerarea {
    height: 80%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Sorry for the bother. If you could point me to any guides/tutorials that cover information then I would be grateful.

EDIT: Also, it is important to note that this behavior only occurs when I use percentage. When I use a pixel measurement (Up to 130px, since the font size is 20 px), the padding is added from the end of the "Banner" class div, which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical padding or margin uses parent's width as référence when used width % value.

You may try using an extra element or pseudo element to fill the area where you want padding apllied, using height inheritance.

This would be with empty pseudo:

```
.banner {height:150px;}
.center, .bannerspace {height:100%;}
.bannerspace:before , .bannerspace:after {
content:'';
display:block;
height:10%;
}
```

Mind too the use of `box-sizing`.

Comment: I would be willing to make an extra element or pseudo-element, but then I run into the same problem. If I want the div's padding to expand relative to the banner's height in case of changes later, how would I do that? I'm also not sure if your first sentence meant to say height or if you were talking about horizontal padding.